# How do I remove YouTube logo from a video?

Tags: javascript, html

I inserted `modestbranding=1`, but it doen't work: YouTube logo is still there.

```html
<a href="#null" onclick="document.getElementById('player').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/dPvIx8Ughkm?modestbranding=1&controls=0...">
```

Comment: Do you use the `showinfo=0` parameter, too? They don't work together.

Comment: @Nippey, I removed `showinfo=0` and got another issue (label of video and logo at the top right corner). is there a way to completely remove everything except the video itself ? Or, maybe keep the logo, but prevent the click event on it.

Comment: [Please visit this Question for answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496186/how-can-i-remove-youtube-logo-from-the-youtube-player-for-use-in-other-applicati

Comment: [Please visit this Question For Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496186/how-can-i-remove-youtube-logo-from-the-youtube-player-for-use-in-other-applicati

Comment: @Mrugesh inline link: `[Link label](url)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also use the `showinfo` parameter?
If so, it can't be used together with `modestbranding`.

[Here](http://www.reelseo.com/remove-youtube-logo/) is a nice article about this.

Not using the `showninfo` parameter will cause the logo and the label to reappear.
The label can be *removed* by setting the title to nothing `&title=&controls=0`
(Notice the `=` is directly followed by the next parameter, the `controls` parameter is just there to illustrate *nothing* ;] )

If you need more control, you can consider using an alternative player like the [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players).