# How can I remove youtube logo from the youtube player for use in other application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, youtube-api

I want to use the Charmless youtube player in my application and I want to remove youtube logo from the Player. How can i achieve this thing? My application is developed using AS3.

Comment: please post your AS3 code where you are embedding the youtube link and i'll be glad to assist you on how to specify the parameters required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to remove youtube logo by many ways. But I didn't get success to remove it from the youtube player.

Finally I check the youtube player functionality and behavior. When video is attached to the player then it will be displayed in center. if player container height is bigger then video height so both (top and bottom) side Black strip will be appeared. Just we have to hide the Black Strip from the user display area using masking concept. (In Flash we can apply the mask to container and same thing will be done using the DOM model in Javascript.)

In directly it will be removed as per end user perspective not actually. so Indirect way youtube logo is removed from the player.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `?modestbranding=1` to the end of your URL.

See more [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

> modestbranding (supported players: AS3, HTML5)
>   This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. 
>   Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar.
>   Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused 
>   video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.

Comment: I am developing Flash Application and I am using this URL "http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3" to get youtube Video Player. Where I have to add your given querystring. I added in this url but not working..

Comment: if you use more than one get parameter you separate them via &, not ?. so use `youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1`

Comment: Apparently, for the chromeless player, the `modestbranding` has no effect unless the `showinfo` parameter is also set to 1. Example: [apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1&showinfo=1](http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1&showinfo=1)

Comment: you still have failed to supply us with any part of your code, thus far it's virtually impossible to assist you further.

Answer (score 1):

try this API player code.

http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1&showinfo=1

Chromeless player, the modestbranding has no effect unless "showinfo=1" is must for API player.

Answer (score -2):

you can try GKPlugin this plugin using JWPlayer 5.x at:

```
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0OhZLpuvlSRTDZLMXowQWNMZTA#list
```